# Magento 2 - PayPal no choice for different billing & shipping address

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal

somehow Paypal acts strange. When checking out for our clients on Magento 2.3.X, they cannot chose different billing and shipping adresses. For all other payment methods that works.

See here. For Klarna, choice is given:

[image]

For PayPal somehow not:

[image]

Does anyone have an idead, how I can show the chechbox "My billing and shipping address are the same" also for PayPal?

Regards & thanks in advance

Comment: I think, once customer is redirected to the Paypal page, there he can set address and other info details.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is by design.
Let's look at the differences in the templates for klarna and paypal.

Klarna is rendered by the template `vendor/klarna/module-kp/view/frontend/web/template/payments/kp.html` which has this section

```
    <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
```

`getBillingAddressFormName` is a function in the default payment method renderer `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js` which returns `'billing-address-form-' + this.item.method` so a static text plus the name of the payment method.
In this region, the billing address form is added from `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process` method (dig deeper in that class and you end up in the method `getBillingAddressComponent` where you see  `'displayArea' => 'billing-address-form-' . $paymentCode`).
We can talk about how this works for a few hours but the short story is that the billing address form is added to all the payment methods in a specific area and then the method template can decide if it displays it or not and where to display it.

Now let's look at the paypal express method.
This is rendered by the template `vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/payflow-express.html`.
This does not contain any trace of the text `<!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->` so it does not render the billing address form.
The only paypal payment methods that display the form are:

- payflowpro (template `vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/payflowpro-form.html`)
- iframe (template `vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/iframe-methods.html`)
- paypal billing agreement (template `vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal_billing_agreement-form.html`)

If you are using one of these 3 methods and you don't get the billing address form it means I'm wrong and all I wrote above means nothing.
But if I'm right and this is "by design", I cannot answer the question to "why it is like this." Could be what [fmsthird said in the comment above](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313797/magento-2-paypal-no-choice-for-different-billing-shipping-address#comment451671_313797)

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed info Marius. Really appreciated. I will look into this but it sounds reasonable. It would mean that on that assumption if I add "<!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) etc." that it should be in theory possible to add this address functionality, correct?

Comment: in theory yes, but it may be useless, if the server side does not handle this. You can try it just for the sake of it.